# select duplicate columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table 1**

```
Id    Name
1     xxxxx
1     ccccc
2     uuuuu
3     ddddd
```

I want to select where the `Id` have multiple entries with same `Id`

How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can find `id`s with multiple entries and then use `LEFT JOIN`/`IS NOT NULL` pattern to retrieve corresponding data from the original table :

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tbl t1 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id 
            FROM tbl 
            GROUP BY id 
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t2.id IS NOT NULL
```

Other possible solutions include using `EXISTS` or `IN` clauses instead of `LEFT JOIN`/`IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

With [ranking functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
Y as (
select *, count(*) over (partition by id) counter
from X)
select id, name from Y where counter > 1
```